# OSGi ConditionalPermissionAdmin - unable to assign permission to other bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I need to assign permission to bundle in OSGi using ConditionalPermissionAdmin. Permission string looks as follows:

```
ALLOW { [org.osg.service.condpermadmin.BundleLocationCondition "file:d:/temp/*"]
    (org.osgi.framework.PackagePermission "org.osgi.framework" "import")
```

}

Despite this permission appearing in active permission list, when I install and start bundle from d:\temp folder, it causes an exception stating that it can't be resolved:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle
"com.javaworld.sample.HelloWorld_1.0.0.201404031307 [2]" could not be resolved.
Reason: Missing Permission: ("org.osgi.framework.PackagePermission"
"org.osgi.framework" "import"), Missing Constraint: Import-Package:
org.osgi.framework; version="0.0.0"
```

I'm using example from chapter 14 of book named "OSGI in Action", my OSGi implementation is Equinox (org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar), command line for starting OSGi is

```
java -Dorg.osgi.framework.security="osgi" -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar -console
```

Something seems to be missing - I've tried to assign AllPermissions to bundles, yet they still fail to resolve after "admin" bundle starts assigning permission. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure "file:d:/temp/*" will match the actual location strings of the bundles?

Answer (score 0):

Typos are my bane... in permission I've tried to set, I've typed "org.osg.service" instead of "org.osgi.service" - that was enough for this thing to quietly stop working... Problem solved.